# Xml file missed attributes

Tags: java, android

i imported the library from here:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

then i created an xml file with from and back id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/front"
            android:tag="front" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:id="@+id/back"
                     android:tag="back"

                      >

                      <Button
                          android:id="@+id/deleteBtn1"
                          android:layout_width="150dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"
                          android:text="Delete" />

                      <Button
                          android:id="@+id/UpdateBtn1"
                          android:layout_width="150dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"
                          android:text="Update" />

                  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then i created the xml file with the swipeListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:hint="Search">                               
                </EditText>

                <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </ListView>


        <main.java.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
            swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
            swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
            swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
            swipe:swipeMode="both"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

and it shows me an error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- main.java.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.RuntimeException: Missed attribute swipeFrontView or swipeBackView
    at main.java.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView.init(SwipeListView.java:166)
    at main.java.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView.<init>(SwipeListView.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

line 166 is:

```
    throw new RuntimeException("Missed attribute swipeFrontView or swipeBackView");

 if (swipeFrontView == 0 || swipeBackView == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missed attribute swipeFrontView or swipeBackView");
        }
```

and line 121 is:

```
init(attrs);


public SwipeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }
```

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adir I believe the issue may be that you are trying to instantiate the wrong class by using an invalid package name identifier. main.java.**com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView**

Remove main.java from the class name.

Comment: thanks, now it doesnt show me this error, thanks alot! however i have a nullPointerException and i dont know why...i added my updated xml and code and logcat above, please help me

Comment: hi, i have now another problem, it shows me the back layout with the front layout and when i swipe the listview it swipes bothand remain a blank entry, when swipe again it shows me the two layouts...do you know what is the problem can be?