# android swipelist missing attributes

Tags: android, xml, layout, swipe

I have the same problem that this user : [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543252/xml-file-missed-attributes)

But I have the name of the class in my layout xml file correctly typed, and in the xml view it does not give any error, but when I change to graphical layout view I get an error saying :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You forgot the attributes swipeFrontView or swipeBackView.
You can add this attributes or use 'swipelist_frontview' and 'swipelist_backview'     
identifiers
```

I added nineoldandroid and swipe-list jars.

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the ids in SwipeListView to

> ```
> swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/swipelist_backview"
> swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/swipelist_frontview"
> ```

And in the list item view to

> ```
> <FrameLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/swipelist_backview"
>         ...>
>         ...
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/swipelist_frontview"
>         ...>
>         ...
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     </FrameLayout>
> ```

Solved the problem for me. I think this bug is somehow related to this pull request https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/pull/11

Answer (score 2):

swipeListView have 2 views as "FrontView"&"BackView"
try this sample xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/back"
         style="@style/ListBackContent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="110dp"   
         android:tag="back" >

    <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/backshowportion"
             style="@style/ListBackContent"
             android:layout_width="250dp"
             android:layout_height="110dp"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"          
             android:gravity="right|center" >

             <TextView
                     .... />

             <TextView
                     .... />

             <TextView 
                      ..../>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/front"
         style="@style/ListFrontContent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="110dp"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:tag="front" >
         <TextView
                 .... />

         <TextView
                 .... />

         <TextView
                 .... />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need in you list something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="both" />
```